# Unable to convert XML to JSON using [newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode method in powershell

Tags: powershell, json.net

I am trying to convert the content of a xml file to json using powershell.
When I call to the method, the powershell returns the error as below:

```
Method invocation failed because [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert] does not contain a method named 'SerializeXmlNode'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $jsonText = [newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($xmlDoc)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I also checked the newtonsoft website below but the SerializeXmlNode method seemed to not have been deprecated:
[newtonsoft - SerializeXmlNode](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode_1.htm)

Kindly check my script below:

```
Import-Module newtonsoft.json
$filename = "E:\Udemy\Complete Guide to XML For Microsoft Developers\Lecture 5\XMLClass_Downloads_2021_03_28\IntroSamples\Flight01.xml"
#[xml]$xmlDoc = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename) 
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $filename 

Write-Host $xmlDoc.OuterXml
Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------"

$jsonText = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($xmlDoc)
```

How can I convert the xml to json using SerializeXmlNode method or any of its equivalent ?

Kind regards,
Ken

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: I have provided my current script on the post above - you can replace the $filename variable corresponding to your xml file in your machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the latest Json dll from [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases) and unzip it somewhere after you have right-clicked the zip file, selected 'Properties' and unblocked it.
Suppose you have chosen path 'C:\Program Files\NewtonSoft' to store the unzipped folder, then put this at the top of your script:

```
$jsonDllPath = 'C:\Program Files\NewtonSoft\Json130r1\Bin\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
Add-Type -Path $jsonDllPath

$filename = 'E:\Udemy\Complete Guide to XML For Microsoft Developers\Lecture 5\XMLClass_Downloads_2021_03_28\IntroSamples\Flight01.xml'
# load the xml file. This way, you are ensured to get the file encoding correct
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xmlDoc.Load($filename)

Write-Host $xmlDoc.OuterXml
Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------"

# this should now work:
$jsonText = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($xmlDoc)
```

<sup>Depending on the XML, if it has an xml declaration line or not, you may want to use `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($xmlDoc.DocumentElement)`</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution works, I have upvoted and marked your answer as the official solution